# Get the table name where data is updated/inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to get the table name where data is updated/inserted?

```
UPDATE
 a
SET
 a.Salary = a.Salary + 5000
FROM
 dbo.Employee a
INNER JOIN
 dbo.Status b
ON
 a.StatusID = b.ID
WHERE
 b.Description = 'Regular'

SELECT @@TableUpdated
```

Ouput should be `Employee`

Comment: I've never seen such done 'automatically'..

Comment: You cannot NOT know the table when you write a query. Thus it is not expected that you will *query* server about which table was affected. If you have doubts about query syntax you can post it and your question about it here, on SO

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack and can be done only inside a trigger but still you can try this and may help someone to get an idea:

```
CREATE TRIGGER z ON dbo.Employee
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF(UPDATE(a))
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
      FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'Employee' 
             AND COLUMN_NAME = 'a') 
begin
SELECT 'Employee'
end
ELSE  // you can add more if statements
begin
SELECT 'Status'
END
end
```

Once you create trigger, use that update statement you provided in your question, the trigger should return you the name of the table.

Comment: Hmm... will this trigger fire when you do `UPDATE dbo.Status`? No, I guess! So for the generic solution you will have do add the trigger to every table in your database!

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's not gonna be fired in that case. And, I don't think, sql server allows you to create one trigger for multiple tables. So, this can't be a generic solution. You can try accessing sys.sysprocesses view for latest sql command you executed and get table name from there. The problem with this solution is you can't check whether that statement was successfully executed or not (i.e. update/insert really happened).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this sql query to get a list of affected table like this:

```
sstupdate
 a(dbo.Employee)(tetUpdate)
   StatusID
   Salary
   Salary
 dbo.Employee(tetSelect)
 dbo.Status(tetSelect)
   ID
   Description
```